# DB Query Error: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01422 exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512:

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been experiencing the following error on the front end when I try to generate reports on the front end application:

**DB Query Error: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01422 exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at ".AUDIT_REPORT", line 4044. MS Word can not be genrated.**

Following is the function code within the package AUDIT_REPORT in production, where line 4044 (SELECT statement) has the error.

```
FUNCTION AUD_REP (i_aud_id IN VARCHAR2)

RETURN CLOB
IS
   x_details CLOB;
   x_sec_text  varchar2(4000);
   x_sec_ref_num varchar2(1000);
   x_sec_name varchar2(1000);
   x_satisfactory varchar2(1000);
   x_minor varchar2(1000);
   x_major varchar2(1000);
   x_critical varchar2(1000);
   x_na varchar2(1000);
   x_sec_rat varchar2(1000);
   x_last varchar2(1000);


    CURSOR  CAT_Items
    IS 
        select instance_ID from SI_100357_T
        where (audit_id=i_aud_id and rem_action is null) OR (audit_id=i_aud_id and Overall_Comments is not null)
    ORDER by Title, METRIC_COMPLETED_DATE ;
    BEGIN

    x_details := '<body lang=EN-US style=''tab-interval:.5in''>
                  <div class=Section1>
                  <p style=''margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100%
                  style=''width:100%;mso-cellspacing:0in;''>
                   <thead>
                  <tr style=''mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes''>
                   <td width=10% valign=top style=''width:10%; ''>
                  <b><span style=''font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;color:black;text-align:center''>Question</span></b>
                  </td>
                   <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                  <b><span style=''font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;color:black;text-align:center''>Status</span></b>
                  </td>
                   <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                  <b><span style=''font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;color:black;text-align:center''>Completion Date</span></b>
                  </td>   
                    <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                  <b><span style=''font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;color:black;text-align:center''>Current Owner</span></b>
                  </td>
                    <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                  <b><span style=''font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;color:black;text-align:center''>Question Rating</span></b>
                  </td> 
              <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                   <b><span style=''font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;color:black;text-align:center''>Original Due Date</span></b>
                  </td> 
                  <td width=65% valign=top style=''width:65%;''>
                  <b><span style=''font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;color:black;text-align:center''>Overall Comment History</span></b>
                  </td>  
                  </tr>
                  </thead>';


FOR items in CAT_Items

LOOP   
**select BB.TITLE**,
case A.STATUS
when '2' then 'CLOSED'
else 'OPEN' end as STATUS,
Completed.COMPLETE,
F.First_name||' ' ||F.Last_name as Current_Owner,
REM_CUSTOM_COL1,
BB.Issue_Due_Date,
CC.First_name||' '||CC.Last_name||'- '||BB.Event_Creation_Date||'- '||BB.Overall_comments

into x_sec_ref_num,x_sec_name,x_satisfactory,x_minor,x_major,x_critical,x_na

FROM SI_100357_T BB 
left outer join SI_USERS_T CC on BB.Event_user_name=CC.user_name 
left outer join SI_Event_Assignments E on BB.process_instance_ID=E.process_instance_ID
left outer join SI_users_T F on E.user_ID=F.user_ID
left outer join MS_AUD_AUDIT_REMEDIATIONS A on BB.Simplified_CAPA_ID=A.Remediation_ID

left outer join (
select BBB.Metric_Completed_Date as COMPLETE, BBB.Simplified_CAPA_ID as IDENT
from MS_AUD_AUDIT_REMEDIATIONS AAA
left outer join SI_100357_T BBB on AAA.Remediation_ID=BBB.Simplified_CAPA_ID
Where AAA.Audit_ID=i_aud_id and BBB.rem_action='290'
group by 
BBB.Metric_Completed_Date, BBB.Simplified_CAPA_ID) COMPLETED on COMPLETED.IDENT=A.REMEDIATION_ID

Where  (BB.instance_ID=items.instance_ID)
ORDER by REM_CUSTOM_COL1,BB.Title, BB.METRIC_COMPLETED_DATE ;

         x_details :=  x_details ||'
                              <tr style=''mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes''>
                            <td width=10% valign=top style=''width:10%;''>
                            <span style=''font-size:10.0pt;color:black;text-align:center''><span
                            class=SpellE>'||x_sec_ref_num||'</span>
                            </td>
                            <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                            <span style=''font-size:9.0pt;color:black''><span
                            class=SpellE>'||x_sec_name||'</span><o:p>
                            </td>
                            <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                            <span style=''font-size:9.0pt;color:black''><span
                            class=SpellE>'||x_satisfactory||'</span>
                            </td> 
                            <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                            <span style=''font-size:9.0pt;color:black''><span
                            class=SpellE>'||x_minor||'</span>
                            </td>  
                            <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                            <span style=''font-size:9.0pt;color:black''><span
                            class=SpellE>'||x_major||'</span>
                            </td>    
                            <td width=5% valign=top style=''width:5%;''>
                            <span style=''font-size:9.0pt;color:black''><span
                            class=SpellE>'||x_critical||'</span>
                            </td>         
                            <td width=65% valign=top style=''width:65%;''>
                            <span style=''font-size:8.0pt;color:black''><span
                            class=SpellE>'||x_na||'</span>
                            </td> 
                            </tr>';

       END LOOP;

    x_details :=  x_details ||'</table>
                                <p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                                </div>
                                </body>';

    RETURN x_details;

END AUD_REP;
```

I initially assumed the SELECT INTO could be wrong because it has to return multiple rows every time. But this code seems to work fine for other audit id's. There are some 7 audit id's that show this error while trying to generate a report. I am not sure how to figure out where the issue lies and where to fix. If this is a data level issue how do I go about it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  You can't select into if more than one row is returned.

Comment: But the confusing part is, this code is working for other audits returning multiple rows. It is just those 7 audits give the mentioned error generating report and also the same code has been working until now with no changes. So that makes me wonder the code is fine and the issue is in the data level. And I am not sure where to head to find the issue.

Comment: well, step through your code in a debugger.